# How does this implemention of quick sort works?

Tags: c

Can someone explain this code snippet I found in "The C Programming Language" book. It is in section 4.10 - Recursion.

```
// swap: interchange v[i] and v[j]
void swap(int v[], int i, int j) {
    int temp;

    temp = v[i];
    v[i] = v[j];
    v[j] = temp;
}

// qsort: sort v[left]...v[right] into increasing order
void qsort(int v[], int left, int right) {
    int i, last;

    if (left >= right) //do nothing if array contains fewer than two elements
        return;

    swap(v, left, (left + right) / 2); // move partition element to v[0]
    last = left;
    for (i = left + 1; i <= right; i++) // partition
        if (v[i] < v[left])
            swap(v, ++last, i);

    swap(v, left, last); // restore parition element
    qsort(v, left, last - 1);
    qsort(v, last + 1, right);
}
```

Comment: Well the code probably implements quicksort.... Would you like to ask a focused question on a specific construct you do not understand? Try to avoid the impression that you have a homework assignment which says "Explain this quicksort implementation." However, if it actually IS an assignment then please have a look here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: Are you wondering how quick sort works in general or is it a specific question about this particular implementation?

Comment: You could focus your question by phrasings like "I am used to implementations doing ... but this does ...". Or "I wonder on the logical construct in line ..., I was expecting it to be ...".

Comment: @klutt it is about the working of this particular implementation. And, this is not an Assignment for homework. Specifically, the for loop and the two lines above it.

Comment: @EpycZen Well, those lines handles the partitioning

Comment: You state that this is about this specific implementation of quicksort, and NOT about quicksort as an algorithm. So please contrast the lines you have trouble understanding to your understanding of quicksort. Maybe phrased like "I know that the loop implements the partitioning, which means .... For that I would implement like ... or like this other implementation .... which is completely clear to me. The difference which puzzles me is ...". You really need to make this question different from "Please explain quicksort algorithm in general, using this example." Thats not a correct question here

Answer (score 1):

## Quicksort in general

The general concept of quicksort can be described with this python inspired pseudocode

```
quicksort(list):
    if length(list) < 2:
        return list

    pivot = getSomeElement(list)
    left  = [x for x in list if x < pivot]
    right = [x for x in list if x >= pivot]

    return quicksort(left) + quicksort(right)
```

First, we have the base case, where the list has zero or one element. The sorting of this is trivial, because it's sorted.

Then we pick a pivot element. Any element will do, but there are more or less clever ways of choosing it. You can pick the first element, but that would give very poor performance on sorted lists. Ideally, you want to pick the median value, since this would make the two partitions equally big. But you don't want to spend too much time on choosing it. And finding the optimum pivot would require a linear search through the whole list at each recursion step. And then you could just as well use bubble sort instead.

After that we simply create two new lists, one with all elements less than the pivot element and one with the rest of them.

Lastly, we call quicksort on these two partitions and concatenate them.

## This particular implementation

As I mentioned above, you can choose pivot element freely. They have chosen to pick the value in the middle of the list, without even considering it's value with this line:

```
swap(v, left, (left + right) / 2);
```

This may seem strange, but the reason is that this will avoid the problem with sorted lists taking long time. For a sorted list, the middle element will be the optimum pivot element, while the elements on the boundaries will be the worst. For a completely random list, this would be just as good as picking the first element. But sending a sorted list to a sorting function is fairly common. Not intentionally of course, but it happens quite often that the list you want to sort just happen to be sorted. So it is a case worth optimizing for. Also, this approach works fairly well for partially sorted lists.

So in short, for just ANY list, the middle element is equally good as any other, but this (very small) overhead is worth it in the real world where already sorted lists are statistically overrepresented.

One way to improve this for unsorted lists with slightly more overhead would be to pick the middle value and then the two values around it. Something like this:

```
int pivot;
if(right-left > 2) {
    int m = (left+right)/2;
    // Function that returns the middle of three arguments
    pivot = getMiddle(v[m-1], v[m], v[m+1]);
} else {
    pivot = (left+right)/2;
}

swap(v, left, pivot);
```

That is, it picks three values and chooses the median of those as a pivot.

The for loop just takes care of the partitioning. The reason it looks very different from the pseudo code is that the pseudo code creates new lists by copying, while this implementation does everything in place by swapping elements.

Comment: This last piece of code is broken for `right-left <= 2` - `swap` will be called with an unilitialized `pivot` value.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Fixed

Comment: Hmm - for e.g. `left==1, right==2` that yields `swap(v, 1, 1);` - is that right?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I took the easy way out, since I only was looking for showing the principle :)

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Also, since the choice of pivot does not affect correctness but only efficiency, it does not matter that much.